# How to pass shipping address details to token, customer, or charge objects?

Tags: javascript, php, stripe-payments

I have a custom HTML form with a stripe card input element to checkout.  I can't seem to find a way to pass the shipping info retrieved from the form to the payment invoice on the stripe dashboard. 
My HTML code:

```
<form action="admin/charge.php" method="post" id="payment-form">
  <div class="form-row">
  <input type="hidden" name="total" value="<?= $stripe_total?>"> </input>
  <input name = "first" type="text" placeholder="First Name*" required maxlength="20" id="first">
   <input name = "last" type="text" placeholder="Last Name*" required maxlength="20" id="last">
   <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address*" id="email" maxlength="30" required> 
   <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" maxlength="10">
   <input name = "addy1" type="text" placeholder="Address Street Name*" required maxlength="35" id="addy1">
   <input name = "addy2" type="text" placeholder="Address 2" maxlength="15" id="addy2">
   <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" placeholder="Zip Code*" required maxlength="11">
     <input type="text" name="city" id="city" placeholder="City*" required maxlength="20">
    <select name="state" id="state">
<option value="State">State</option>
    //every state
</select>
    <select     required name="country" id="country">
    <option value='Countries'>Countries</option>
    //every country option
</select>



    <div id="card-element"></div>

    <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
  </div>   

  <button>Submit Payment</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
// JavaScript Document
// Create a Stripe client.
var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_PHnlKn4Jd72hlJjWPtQqDR1G00U2vyOtMP');

// Create an instance of Elements.
var elements = stripe.elements();

// Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
// (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
var style = {
  base: {
    color: '#32325d',
    fontFamily: '"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif',
    fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
    fontSize: '16px',
    '::placeholder': {
      color: '#aab7c4'
    }
  },
  invalid: {
    color: '#fa755a',
    iconColor: '#fa755a'
  }
};

// Create an instance of the card Element.
var card = elements.create('card', {
    style: style,
    hidePostalCode:true,
    })
;

// Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
card.mount('#card-element');

// Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
card.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  var displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
  if (event.error) {
    displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
  } else {
    displayError.textContent = '';
  }
});

// Handle form submission.
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  stripe.createToken(card,tokenData).then(function(result) {
    if (result.error) {
      // Inform the user if there was an error.
      var errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
      errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    } else {
      // Send the token to your server.
      stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
    }
  });
});

// Submit the form with the token ID.
function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
  // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
  var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
  var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
  hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
  form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

  // Submit the form
  form.submit();
}
```

and php:

```
<?php
require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');
require_once('config.php');
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_key');

$POST = filter_var_array($_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$token = $POST['stripeToken'];
$first = $POST['first'];
$last = $POST['last'];
$email = $POST['email'];
$phone = $POST['phone'];
$addy1 = $POST['addy1'];
$addy2 = $POST['addy2'];
$zip = $POST['zip'];
$city = $POST['city'];
$state = $POST['state'];
$country = $POST['country'];
$total = $POST['total'];


 $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
 "email"    => $email,
 "source"   => $token,
 "address" => array(
      "line1" => "Test line 1",
      "line2" => "Test Line 2",
      "city" => "My City",
      "postal_code" => "90210",
      "state" => "CA",
      )
 ));

 $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "billingAddress"=> true,
 "shippingAddress"=>true,
 "amount"   => $total,
 "currency" => "usd",
 "description"  => "BFM Purchase",
 "customer"     => $customer->id,
 "shipping" => array(
 "address" => array(
      "name" => $first,
      ))
 ));



  print_r($charge);
echo "     break     ";
 print_r($customer);
?>
```

Okay, as far as things that I tried, I tried to add billing_details to the charge and customer objects, but I receive an error that billing_details in an unknown parameter. I think there is a spot where I can set that parameter to "true" but I don't know where and what to do from there. The next thing I see from the Stripe documentation is that I can pass the create token function in the js a second parameter which contains an object of the additional details I need, however, I don't know how to do this in the javascript. 
Here: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference 
the docs refer to this as a dataToken, so then how can I create a custom Stripe token with shipping details and append that to the stripe token with the card info? Alternatively, I thought i could create a brand new token, pass it the important data from the stripe created token, then expand the shipping details in the new token once in the php file. 
Any help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: It seems very uncommon to use library without to `include` or `use` statement in php, have you tried to `use \Stripe\Stripe;` and then instantiate on object? of ` \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('sk_test_key');` ?

Comment: I am unsure what you mean. The code runs fine and the APIs work etc, the only problem is that under the 'payment' section of the dashboard, the address appears as 'no address'. My only concern at the moment is somehow associated the address values from the form to the charge. The address does show for the customer, however, I want the payment invoice to show the address for shipping.

Comment: check if it does come to php file by `var_dump($_POST)` array.

Comment: The POST data does arrive soundly. It is finding a way to pass that data to the stripe charge object that is the problem. I did a var dump and all the post data asked for in the php arrives.

Comment: The above code functions and creates the test charge. However, I simply do not know how to append the address variables to the Charge Object

Comment: give me the link to github of what you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer, all on my lonesome :(.
But basically it is much easier to add these details to a source and charging that source rather than a token. I followed the documentation from this link: 
https://stripe.com/docs/sources/customers
Hope this can help a fellow struggler.